# Oracle analytical function

Tags: oracle, function, analytical

I have similar problem. Can you anyone give me solution.
Below is the table value

```
    10    
    20    
    30   
    40
```

I want output like this

```
10  10-2     8    
20  20-8    12    
30  30-12   18    
40  40-18   22
```

Sort by ascending and always substract 2 for the first recrod and use the result for the subsequent records.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in one query. But generating a sequence is something programming languages are very good at.

Answer (score 6):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d0ac/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( VAL ) AS
          SELECT 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 30 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 40 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH Parities AS (
  SELECT VAL,
         MOD( ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY VAL ), 2 ) AS Parity
  FROM   TEST
)
SELECT VAL,
       ABS( SUM( CASE PARITY WHEN 1 THEN -VAL ELSE VAL END ) OVER ( ORDER BY VAL ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) + 2 ) AS total
FROM   Parities
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5d0ac/6/0)**:

```
| VAL | TOTAL |
|-----|-------|
|  10 |     8 |
|  20 |    12 |
|  30 |    18 |
|  40 |    22 |
```

Comment: Excellent, simple and powerful logic.  Thanks a lot

Comment: @Bala - if this has answered your question then you can mark the answer as correct  to indicate the question is closed. If not, then you can post what other issues there are.

Comment: I take my hat off to you! *{  :-)  That is impressive stuff!

Answer (score 0):

For completness - basic, recursive solution:

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d17e1/1)</sup>

```
with t(val, n) as (
  select val, val-2 from test where val = 10
  union all select test.val, test.val-n from test, t where test.val = t.val + 10 )
select * from t
```